# add components to a panel in Java

Tags: java, components, addition, japplet

I'm creating an applet which consists of a class which extends JApplet, with a menubar and a class which extends a JPanel.(So there is a menubar and a JPanel shown in the applet).

In this class I add and remove some textfields to the JPanel. This all works fine. Here's where it gets tricky: it only works the first time. When I add some new textfields to the JPanel, they are added and visible in the JPanel, but the menubar in the JFrame stops working.

Since the code is too extensive I'll only post parts of it.

Here's the code where I add the JPanel to the JApplet:

```
public class Simulator extends JApplet implements ItemListener, ActionListener {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    pane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
}
```

Here's the code of the JPanel:

```
class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(textfield != null)
            remove(textfield);
        textfield = new JTextField();
        this.add(textfield);
    }
}
```

This works the first time(when nothing is removed), but the second time the menubar stops working.
When I leave out the this.add(textfield); line, the menubar keeps working.

Comment: What do you mean by "the menubar stops working"? Can you still click some items? Might be that the submenus get rendered behind your newly added textfield ...

Comment: You should not add and remove textfields in `paintComponent()`. `paintComponent` is for painting the component only!

Comment: @Jeroen You can still open the menu, but the submenu's don't show. After looking closely, I noticed a small blue line which only appears when opening the menu, so I guess they do get rendered behind something else. But the textfields aren't in the way of the menu. Here's a picture: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1333934/menu%20open.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had similar problems with popup menus beeing painted behind other components.
Try calling static `JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);` or the `setLightWeightPopupEnabled` on your specific submenu. This will make (all) popup menus (i.e. submenus) to heavy weight components that have a native peer.

Comment: I called `(menu.getPopupMenu()).setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);` which fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into issues with threading. Adding and removing JComponents *during painting* might mess up the EDT (which is calling the paint method in the first place).